# how can i make an interface in php to add data csv file

Tags: php, javascript, csv

hey...i need to create a html+php+javascript interface

where i got three text area  and i want::::

that if i'll enter some data into text area and pressing submit button,,then it'll enter that textarea's data into a csv file..

pls some one help....

Comment: Please make clear about your question, the best is a simple example shows specifically how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $_GET['TextArea']);
fclose($fp);

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$list = arrary(); 
//your array will have all the fields from the form, textfields and textareas

$fp = fopen('output.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```